# when time wait condition will close in tcp level

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

when tcp level connection is created between application and server as below

tcp        0      0 10.3.7.73:59906             10.3.7.73:1033              ESTABLISHED

when i disconnect or drop the connection then it will move to time wait state

tcp        0      0 10.3.7.73:59906             10.3.7.73:1033              TIME_WAIT

after some time it will disappear.

so how much time will take close completely from time wait state

Comment: @CodeCaster It has nothing to do with SO_LINGER. There is a linger setting that avoids the TIME_WAIT state altogether, but no setting that affects its duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) sets the TIME-OUTto be twice the Maximum Segment Lifetime, or 2MSL. Since MSL, the maximum time a packet can wander around Internet, is set to 2 minutes, 2MSL is 4 minutes.

Pls. see the answer to https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait for more detailed explanation.